# Exporting BigQuery Audiences to Google Analytics for remarketing

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

Using BigQuery, I have created several audiences based on Google Analytics data, but I need to find a way to export these audiences into Google Analytics 360 and/or into Google Adwords for remarketing purposes. 
I am inquiring about the best way to go about doing this? Is it possible? Are there ways to automate this process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find [this article](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/crm-integration) useful, it describes how this can be achieved by uploading audiences to Google Analytics, and from there into SA360.

I would also recommend you take a look at [CRMint](https://github.com/google/crmint), a pipeline tool built for exactly thsi job, as it has a built in worker for [sending audiences to GA](https://github.com/google/crmint/issues/42).

Here is an [intro I wrote to CRMint](https://medium.com/@singularbean/data-pipelines-for-everyone-with-crmint-ff75d4c0875c), you may find it useful.